# Show View in the main page itself (eg: sample.com) in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to show my View on the main page. Suppose that I have an application called "Sample". When a user comes to sample.com it will go to the sample.com/Home/Index. Is there any way/method to show the view in *sample.com* itself as we do in pure HTML Pages? Even though I've done several google-search I ended up in misleading content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set RouteConfig:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Result:

```
http://localhost:51225/Home/Index/1 => Index.html
http://localhost:51225/Home/Index/ => Index.html
http://localhost:51225/Home/ => Index.html
http://localhost:51225/ => Index.html

http://sample.com/Home/Index/1 => Index.html
http://sample.com/Home/Index/ => Index.html
http://sample.com/Home/ => Index.html
http://sample.com/ => Index.html
```

You can learn more at:
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc

Comment: If the answer doesn't work for you let me know.  @Sangeeth Sajan